# What is the best day in the year to take a bath in Ganga river?

Tags: ganga

Bathing in Ganga is considered as extremely auspicious.
I want to know What is the best time to take Ganga-Snan ( bath in the Ganga river) ?

Comment: Daśaharā & Vāruṇī are the rarest occasions to take bath in the Gaṅga.

Comment: @অনু What is Varuni ?

Comment: Caitra kṛṣṇa trayodaśī is referred to as Vāruṇī tithi. A bath in the Gaṅgā on this day is considered equivalent to taking bath  in the Gaṅga for a 100 solar eclipses. It becomes Mahāvāruṇī if Śatabhiṣā star is in the ascendant on that day & Mahāmahāvāruṇī if the both the tithi & star are obtained on a Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

Ganga is holy river, you can take holy bath in it throughout the year specially brahma Muhurta is considered the best time to take a pilgrimage bath though but Kumbh and Ganga Dussehra days are the best time to take bath.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).